# windows.sendkeys equivalent in flex/adobe air

Tags: apache-flex, air, adobe, keyboard-events, sendkeys

Is it possible to capture user typed inputs from keyboard and overwrite user entered text with pre-defined words in Flex/Adobe Air? I'm looking for a  functionality in Adobe Air something like "typinator" does.

Comment: Flex controls will only capture the input if it is given the focus.  this is true for both AIR and Flex web apps.  I don't know what typinator or windows.sendkeys do, though, so I'm not sure if that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.

You can set up a `KeyListener` event on the `stage`, and it should catch any and all keystrokes.  After that, you can send whatever command you like to whatever component you like.  If you are looking to access programs *outside* of AIR, like `windows.sendkeys` can do, please [look at this post](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html) for how that might work.

Specific components can `stopPropagation()`, but I don't think text input objects do this by default.  See this [doc for more on capture/bubble](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_08.html).